# How to automating Putty Shell task on Windows 7?

Tags: ssh, script, automation, scp

I am interested in connecting by shell (Putty or another tool) (I have cygwin and OpenSSH ) 
This is what I wish to accomplish:

1. Upload some files by scp (from Windows 7)
2. Connect to the remote server
3. ssh from that server to another remote server
4. Run scripts (the files I uploaded earlier) and wait for them to finish.
5. Download the files the scripts generated from the system.

Here is what I have:

1. I have the folders where all the files will be both on the local machine and the remote server.
2. I know how long the scripts will take to run.
3. I can approximate the time it will take to upload and download the files(they are very small).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) supports command-line use.  WinSCP scripting allows you to automate a connection to a remote server, as well as uploading files to the remote server via SCP.  You can run a script on the remote server with WinSCP using the CALL command, then download the results, also using WinSCP.  Here's a link to the WinSCP scripting and automation page: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting.